# ascii characters to avoid in passwords

Tags: security, passwords, web-deployment

I recently started web development using django. While working on the user registration page, 
I was researching few things on the password.

Web sites generally place restrictions on the characters that can be used in password. For example spaces or angle brackets cannot be used .

Because all inputs are cleaned and hashed before they are stored to the Database, using any printable ascii characters in password shouldn't really be a problem... right? or am I missing anything.

Comment: I believe most encourage the use of special characters and prohibit use of common words and phrases to counter dictionary attacks

Comment: This drives me crazy about several websites. Banks are the worst. My bank password used to be **enforced** 6-8 characters all lowercase. I called their corporate office and complained and personally got that one changed. Many, many password policies have nothing whatsoever to do with a correct understanding of security.

Comment: ASP.NET will prevent input sequences containing `<` characters because [Request Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) prevents them in a mis-guided attempt to stop [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Most of the time, the only reason to exclude spaces or any printable ASCII character is because of bad coding.

The other times, it's for disambiguation of similar-looking characters for autogenerated passwords (I-l-1, O-0, etc.).

Comment: Avoiding look-alike symbols only makes sense for auto-generated passwords. If your users provides their own passwords, avoiding look-alike symbols is meaningless.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about auto-generated codes, is there a white list for latin characters + numeric values that is OK to use?

Answer (score 1):

Your only concern with contents of passwords should be about Unicode normalization. There are subtle differences in the Unicode symbols generated by different operating systems — for example, some might encode letters like "à" as a single character (`U+00E0`), while others might produce "à" (two characters: the plain latin letter `a`, followed by the [combining grave accent character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) `U+0300`). You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization) Unicode passwords before hashing them in order to make sure that when your users type their passwords on different operating systems, such differences would not prevent them from gaining access to their accounts.

```
>>> a1 = u'à'
>>> a2 = u'à'
>>> a1
u'\xe0'
>>> a2
u'a\u0300'
>>> a1 == a2
False
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>> normalize('NFC', a1) == normalize('NFC', a2)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll keep it in mind when I'll start internationalizing my code.

Comment: Your users are not limited to entering passwords only in the language of your interface.

Comment: True. But shouldn't django take care of it? I'll take a look at the code to see if django has taken this into consideration.

Comment: Since you're asking about password restrictions, I assumed that you're setting up your own solution instead of using the bundled `django.contrib.auth`. I have no idea if they've addressed this concern either.